# Urn model with replacement where each ball has a different number

Tags: probability, combinatorics, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have $N = 10$ balls where each ball has its own number. Thus, $C = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. We draw $n = 4$ times and each time we put the ball back.

What is the probability to draw 4 balls where each ball has a different number?

The only solution I can come up with is:

If we draw a ball the first time there are $10$ allowed numbers. The next time we draw there are $9$ allowed numbers and so on. Thus, $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 = 5040$ draws that are allowed. There are $10^4 = 10000$ possible draws.

Now, we get $\frac {5040}{10000} = 0.504$.

Is there a different solution?

Comment: No, what you did is fine.

Comment: "*Is there a* **different** *solution*"  That depends on what you mean by "different."  One could appeal to rules of conditional probability and multiply out that way instead, getting the probability that all are different is the probability that each ball is different than the previous balls given that all previous balls were different than eachother, giving $\dfrac{9}{10}\times\dfrac{8}{10}\times\dfrac{7}{10}$, but that gives the same answer as before and the underlying principles are the same as to how they work.

Comment: @DonThousand it's fine, yes. But the methodology is not very good. Look at my new solution.

Comment: @JMoravitz Look at my new solution to see what I actually meant.

Comment: It seems you disagree, but I'd say your methodology as given in the original is clearer and more direct than the one in your answer below.  Perhaps it's more *ad hoc*, but I don't see that as a weakness, unless your aim is to answer a whole class of problems in one blow.